# Is there a way I can extract an interface code from a class in VB on visual studio 2008 like C# does?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In C# code, we can just right click on the class name and then select refactor and then extract the interface for that class.

I wonder if this could be done on VB. Im using the same IDE VS 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in a vanilla Visual Studio 2008 install.  There are 3rd party add-ins which support this behavior such as Resharper.